# posix-spawn issue on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, gitlab

I was running GitLab 5.2 I believe on FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE for months and things were going well, no obvious issues I could see.

I've recently upgraded to 6.0 following the guide provided on gitlab.org, unfortunately I'm now getting errors like the following:

```
No such file or directory - posix_spawnp
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:187:in `_pspawn'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:187:in `pspawn'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:160:in `spawn'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb:307:in `popen4'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn/child.rb:105:in `exec!'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn/child.rb:80:in `initialize'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab-grit-2.6.0/lib/grit/git.rb:341:in `new'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab-grit-2.6.0/lib/grit/git.rb:341:in `native'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab-grit-2.6.0/lib/grit/git.rb:368:in `method_missing'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab-grit-2.6.0/lib/grit/repo.rb:558:in `log'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab_git-2.1.0/lib/gitlab_git/repository.rb:180:in `log'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab_git-2.1.0/lib/gitlab_git/commit.rb:52:in `find'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab_git-2.1.0/lib/gitlab_git/commit.rb:64:in `last'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab_git-2.1.0/lib/gitlab_git/repository.rb:90:in `has_commits?'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/gitlab_git-2.1.0/lib/gitlab_git/repository.rb:96:in `empty?'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/app/models/repository.rb:17:in `empty?'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/app/models/project.rb:345:in `empty_repo?'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/lib/tasks/gitlab/check.rake:519:in `block in check_repos_post_receive_hooks_is_link'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in find_each'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `each'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:21:in `block in find_each'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:72:in `find_in_batches'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:20:in `find_each'
/tank/gitlab/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/querying.rb:8:in `find_each'
```

I'm definately not an expert but I'm not sure if FreeBSD offers any posix compatibility. I've manually installed the posix-spawn gem but it made no difference. I was unable to find  help through my searching, the only similar cases I could see came down to missing pygments but I have that installed.

Is it not possible to use GitLab on FreeBSD with the later versions? I see that the unofficial FreeBSD/GitLab install guides are only for 5.1 and 5.2 so that might be an indication. It would be a shame if this is so, GitLab is a great piece of software and I hate to have to drop it.

Appreciate some insights, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the correct path to **git** is set in **gitlab/config/gitlab.yml** as FreeBSD installs ports/packages to /usr/local by default:

```
git:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin/git
```

Then restart GitLab.

How to debug this:

Print the vars of the function in to **gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9/gems/posix-spawn-0.3.6/lib/posix/spawn.rb** on line **187** (adjust if needed):

```
puts "DEBUG"
puts env
puts argv
puts options
      _pspawn(env, argv, options)
```

Run Application Status:

```
# bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production

{}
[["/usr/bin/git", "/usr/bin/git"], "--git-dir=/home/git/repositories/root/git-playground-project.git", "rev-parse", "HEAD"]
{:in=>#<IO:fd 13>, #<IO:fd 14>=>:close, :out=>#<IO:fd 16>, #<IO:fd 15>=>:close, :err=>#<IO:fd 18>, #<IO:fd 17>=>:close}
```

Find the debug lines and verify the parameters.

Good luck!